# Understanding a proof that $z\mapsto z^n$ is a covering map from $S^1$ to $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Let $S^1 = \{z\in\mathbb C : |z|=1\}$. Define $p:S^1\to S^1$ by $p(z) = z^n$, $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. Then $p$ is a covering map.

The proof in question states that the sheets of $S^1\setminus\{1\}$ are $n$ disjoint open arcs of angle $2\pi/n$ in the covering space $S^1$, and $p^{-1}(\{1\})$ contains the endpoints of all these arcs.

I get that $$p^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{e^{2\pi k i/n} : k=0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$$ and these arcs are between the points in this set. But what is meant by "sheets" and what is the significance that $p^{-1}(\{1\})$ contains their endpoints? I do not see how this shows that every point $z\in S^1$ has a neighborhood that is evenly covered by $p$. Is it that the slices of an open set $U\subset S^1$ are these (open) arcs?

Edit: I have an alternative "proof." For $z=e^{it}\in S^1$, choose the neighborhood $U= \{e^{it}:t-\pi i/|n| < t < t+\pi i/|n|\}$. Then it is claimed that the sheets over $U$ consist of $|n|$ disjoint open arcs of $S^1$, evenly spaced about the circle. Intuitively it makes sense, but how can I see it rigorously? Were this to be the case, then letting said arcs be $V_1,\ldots,V_n$, the restrictions $p\vert V_j :V_j\to U$ are homeomorphisms as both $V_j$ and $U$ are homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ and the map $p$ is invertible; namely $p^{-1}(z) = z^{1/n}$ which is clearly continuous.

Comment: What would be understanding in the case of a proof that is wrong or incomplete? Giving a proper proof?

Comment: Completing the proof, yes.

Comment: Take any point $a=re^{it}$ in the target $S^1$. Then $p^{-1}(a)$ consists of the points $a_k:=r^{1/n}e^{i\theta_k}:=r^{1/n}e^{i(t+2\pi k)/n}$, for $k=0,1,2,...,n-1$. Take neighbourhoods $U_k:=(r^{1/n}e^{i(\theta_k-\epsilon)},r^{1/n}e^{i(\theta_k+\epsilon)})$ of each $a_k$. They are mapped by $p$ to the neighbourhood $U:=(re^{i(t-n\epsilon)},re^{i(t+n\epsilon)})$. Note that if we take $\epsilon$ small enough, for example smaller than $1/n$, then $p$ maps $U_k$ injectively. The [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Holomorphic_functions) ...

Comment: ... tells you that $p$ is a homeomorphism (the continuous inverse part, surjectivity is direct and injectivity is from the choice of $\epsilon$) to $U$ when restricted to each $U_k$.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might recall that for any covering map $f : X \to Y$, the definition of an evenly covered open subset $U \subset Y$ is that $f^{-1}(U)$ decomposes as a disjunion union $\cup_{i \in I} V_i$ of open subsets of $X$, for each of which the restricted map $f : V_i \to U$ is a homeomorphism. Those sets $V_i$ are called the *sheets* of the decomposition, the same as what you are calling *slices*, I suppose. There might be still other words for them, I tend to like the word *pancakes*, perhaps because I'm typing this before breakfast.

The significance of the endpoints is just a descriptor for this example, to make sure you have the right picture in your head. They are not important as a concept of covering theory itself.

What this example shows is that every point $p \in S^1 \setminus \{1\}$ has an evenly covered open neighborhood, namely the neighborhood $S^1 \setminus \{1\}$. And if you understand that, then you can probably do the one remaining case: What is an evenly covered open neighborhood of $1$ itself?

Comment: The term *slices* comes from Munkres' text, which are exactly what you are calling *sheets*. Different terminology, I suppose.

Comment: I understand that for $z\in S^1\setminus\{1\}$, the neighborhood $S^1\setminus\{1\}$ of $z$ is evenly covered, as $$p^{-1}(S\setminus\{1\})=\bigcup_{j=0}^{n-1} V_j$$ where $V_j =\{e^{it}:2\pi ij/n < t < 2\pi I(j+1)/n\}$ are disjoint.

Comment: And the restriction $p\vertV_j : V_j \to S^1\setminus \{1\}$ is a homeomorphism as both are homeomorphic to $(0,1)$. But what about $z=1$?

Comment: Well, $S^1 \setminus \{1\}$ is an evenly covered open neighborhood for every single point $z \in S^1$ *except* for $z=1$. So yes, you cannot use $S^1 \setminus \{1\}$ as a neighborhood of $1$. However, can you with your imagination visualize a neighborhood of $1$ in $S^1$, just any neighborhood at all? And can you visualize a neighborhood which, not actually the SAME as $S^1 - \{1\}$, nonetheless is enough LIKE $S^1 - \{1\}$ that it stands a good chance of being evenly covered?

Comment: Actually I just realized that given the way $V_j$ is defined, $e^{2\pi ij/n}\notin\bigcup_{j=0}^{n-1}V_j$ for $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1$. So we have this problem for $n$ points, not just the point $1$.

Comment: Also, it should be $V_j = \{e^{it}:2\pi j/n<t<2\pi (j+1)/n\}$.

Comment: It seems that the fact that this covering map $f :X \to Y$ has domain $X = S^1$ and range $Y=S^1$ which are the same space is confusing you. To help straighten things out, keep in mind that an evenly covered open set is an open subset of the *range*, and that's how you should think of $U = S^1 \setminus \{1\}$. Also, the slices are subsets of the *domain* and that's how you should think of each $V_j$. So there's no "problem" for the domain points $2\pi i j/n$, they are just the domain points with $f$-images equal to the unique point $1$ not in the range subset $S^1 \setminus \{1\}$.

Comment: Okay, I see now. But what is the neighborhood of $z=1$ which is evenly covered by $p$? $U=S^1\setminus\{-1\}$?

Comment: Yup, that looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space):

> The homeomorphic copies in $C$
>   of an evenly covered neighborhood $U$ are called the sheets over $U$ (where $p:C \to X$ is the covering map in question).

followed by some pictorial descriptions.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/255802/4280) gives a nice explanation why $z \to z^n$ is a covering map of $\Bbb S^1$.

Comment: That proof was excessively long and hard to follow.

Comment: @Math1000 And plagued with errors too. Not grave errors, but they probably make it harder to follow.